# Can I use two types of barcode on Fast Report?

Tags: performance, delphi, report, fastreport

I'm want develop a system to print barcode using fastreport, but, I want print Code128B for numbers < 13 and EAN13 for numbers = 13.

How I can use two (2) types of barcode in my report? I using a databand.

Thanks!

- I using Delphi and Fast Report 4.9

Answer (score 1):

In your dataset make calculated fields for the numbers. If the number < 13 characters, set its value in the first field, if its 13 set it in the second.

Then place two barcode controls and make each display one of the fields. The other will be empty so it will not display anything.

This solution is probably easier and certainly faster than making FastReports handle this through scripting.

Comment: If I'll do this:

procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if BarCode1.value = 13 then           
       BarCode1.BarType := bcCodeEAN13;                                                
  else
       BarCode1.BarType:= bcCode128B;                         
end;

Is this work?

thank you!

Comment: Have you tried? I think you need to check the length instead of the value: `if Length(BarCode1.value) ... `